# How do I remove an object from a LinkedList of objects, and from the LinkedLists of all of those objects?

Tags: java, oop, linked-list

I've been trying to write a method that can remove not only on object(User) from a LinkedList(allUsers), but also from the individual LinkedLists that all of the Users have. Can anyone explain to me why this is wrong? I have included the method in question and the User class.

```
public void removeUser(User u){
    //curr equal to front of users list
    Node curr=allUsers.getFront();
    //loop to remove friend from FriendsList
    while(!curr.getNext().getData().equals(u)||curr.getNext()!=null){
        curr=curr.getNext();
    }
    if(curr.getNext()!=null)
        allUsers.remove(allUsers.indexOf(curr.getNext().getData()));
    //loop to run through allUsers
    curr=allUsers.getFront();
    while(curr!=null){  
        if(curr.getData().getFriends().size()!=0){
            //run through friends LinkedLists of each user
            Node curr2=curr.getData().getFriends().getFront();
            while(curr2!=null){
                if(curr2.getData().equals(u))
                    curr2.getData().removeFriend(u);
                curr2=curr2.getNext();  
            }
        }
        curr=curr.getNext();
    }
}
```

User class:

```
public class User{ 
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private int birthYear;
    private LinkedList friends;
    public User(String n, String l, int b){
        name=n;
        location=l;
        birthYear=b;
        friends=new LinkedList();
    }
    public String getName(){return name;}
    public String getLocation(){return location;}
    public int getBirthYear(){return birthYear;}
    public boolean equals(User u){
        if(this.getName().equals(u.getName())&&this.getLocation().equals(u.getLocation())&&this.getBirthYear()==u.getBirthYear())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public LinkedList getFriends(){return friends;}
    public int getNumFriends(){return friends.size();}
    public String toString(){
        return name+" from "+location;
    }
    public void addFriend(User u){friends.addToEnd(u);}
    public void removeFriend(User u){
        if(friends.indexOf(u)!=-1)
            friends.remove(friends.indexOf(u));
    }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with `allUsers.remove(u)` for the first part (I'm not sure what you're asking with the second part of your question). You should design it so you don't have to iterate through the list yourself, and let `LinkedList` handle finding the right object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the LinkedList do the work for you:

```
   public void removeUser(User u){
      while (allUsers.remove(u)) {
        // this loops continue until there are no more entries of user in allUsers (as defined by the User.equals() method)
      }
      // now remove this user from all the remaining user's friends list
      for (User user : allUsers) {
        while (user.getFriends().remove(u)) {
          // remove all occurances
        }
      }
   }
```